# Can I use BlueStacks 4 as an emulator for android in Delphi Tokyo?

Tags: android, delphi

I have tried to use BlueStacks 4 as an android emulator in Delphi Tokyo and the created applications are installed, but they are not executed. I changed some suggested settings on the Web and nothing.

[image]

Comment: I have used BlueStacks in the past as an emulator for Delphi apps, but not lately so I don't know if it still works. I do recall that when it did work, it was pretty slow, though.  But that is typical of many Android emulators.

Comment: My only recommendation: use a real device. It saves a lot of time and headaches